# How to transform a "nested for each" to Java 8 Lambda/Stream construct?

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

How do you transform the following block of code:

```
List<ExecutableElement> methods = ...
List<ExecutableElement> hiddens = new ArrayList<>();
for (ExecutableElement hider : methods) {
  for (ExecutableElement hidden : methods) {
    if (elements.hides(hider, hidden) || elements.overrides(hider, hidden, type)) {
      hiddens.add(hidden);
    }
  }
}
methods.removeAll(hiddens);
```

Into something like:

```
methods.removeAll(methods.stream().filter(... ...().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? What's the problem? Why not use `removeIf()` instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

flatMap should do the trick :

For each ExecutableElement, iterate over all the ExecutableElement and find all the elements hidden by it, then collapse all those streams to a single stream by flatMap, collect it to list, and remove all the hidden elements.

```
methods.removeAll(
    methods.stream ()
           .flatMap (hider -> methods.stream()
                                     .filter (hidden -> elements.hides(hider, hidden) || 
                                                        elements.overrides(hider, hidden, type))
                    )
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```